# Read two files simultaneously line by line

Tags: c++, fasta

I would like to read two `FASTA` files simultaneously line by line. I have the following code to read one file line by line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main( int argc, char **argv ){
    if( argc <= 1 ){
        std::cerr << "Usage: "<<argv[0]<<" [infile]" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::ifstream input(argv[1]);
    if(!input.good()){
        std::cerr << "Error opening '"<<argv[1]<<"'. Bailing out." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::string line, name, content;
    while( std::getline( input, line ).good() ){
        if( line.empty() || line[0] == '>' || line[0] == '@' ){ // Identifier marker
            if( !name.empty() ){ // Print out what we read from the last entry
                std::cout << name << " : " << content << std::endl;
                name.clear();
            }
            if( !line.empty() ){
                name = line.substr(1);
            }
            content.clear();
        } else if( !name.empty() ){
            if( line.find(' ') != std::string::npos ){ // Invalid sequence--no spaces allowed
                name.clear();
                content.clear();
            } else {
                content += line;
            }
        }
    }
    if( !name.empty() ){ // Print out what we read from the last entry
        std::cout << name << " : " << content << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, I want to do it for multiple files. E,g I have two files, file1 and file2. Do the following operation.

```
read file1 line
do some operation
read file2 line
do some operation
repeat till file 1 and file 2 finishes
```

**Note:** I don't want to read all the lines of file1 at once and then all the lines of file2. I want one line from file1 and one from file2, second from file1 and second from file2 and so on.

**Update**

**file1**

```
@r0/1
TATTCTTCCGCATCCTTCATACTCCTGCCGGTCAG
AAA
+
EDCCCBAAAA@@@@?>===<;;9:99987776554678
@r1/1
TGATAGATCTCTTTTTTCGCGCCGACATCTACGCC
+
EDCCCBAAAA@@@@?>===<;;9:99987776554
@r2/1
CACGCCCTTTGTAAGTGGACATCACGCCCTGAGCG
+
EDCCCBAAAA@@@@?>===<;;9:99987776554
```

**file2**

```
@r0/2
GAATACTGGCGGATTACCGGGGAAGCTGGAGC
+
EDCCCBAAAA@@@@?>===<;;9:99987776
@r1/2
AATGTGAAAACGCCATCGATGGAACAGGCAAT
+
EDCCCBAAAA@@@@?>===<;;9:99987776
@r2/2
AACGCGCGTTATCGTGCCGGTCCATTACGCGG
+
EDCCCBAAAA@@@@?>===<;;9:99987776
```

Actually I tried something like

```
std::ifstream input(argv[1]);
std::ifstream input1(argv[2]);
std::string line, name, content;
std::string line1, name1, content1;
    while( std::getline( input, line ).good() && std::getline( input1, line1 ).good() ){

//file1 line operation
// file2 line operation
}
```

But this is not going to work if the lines are different.  The lines after reading will look like

```
@r0/1 TATTCTTCCGCATCCTTCATACTCCTGCCGGTCAGAAA+EDCCCBAAAA@@@@?>===<;;9:99987776554678
```

Comment: You can declare another `std::ifstream` below your existing declaration, e.g. `std::ifstream input(argv[2]);`  You would need to modify your while loop if the files might have different numbers of lines.

Comment: @Bernard How will that work? what will be in the input `argv[1] or argv[2]`.

Comment: @AwaitedOne: Well, _assuming you passed two arguments_, you'd have the first and second argument. Check `argc` to know how many arguments there are. (`argv[0]` by convention is your program name).

Comment: @MSalters I have updated my question, kindly follow update above.

Answer (score 2):

Although it would be easier to tell what kind of parsing you need by having an excerpt of a file. I just went and downloaded this file `Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.22.fa` which is formatted in the following way:

> 22 dna:chromosome chromosome:GRCh38:22:1:50818468:1 REF
>   NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>   CTGGTCTTGAACTCCTGACCTCAAGTGATCTGCCCACCTCCGCCTCCCAAACTGCTAGAA
>   TTACAGGCGTGAGCAACCACTCCCTACCTTCCCCCATTTTTATAATAAACATTCTACACA
>   GGGCTCCTGCCAGCCCTCCAAGCTTCTCACTTTGAGAAGCACAGTCCGCTCTGTCAGACT

Since the first line in unique to the file, and doesn't appear twice, I just removed it, not to burden myself with writing a code for parsing it. However, if your project requires it being present, I will include a  function for going through it as well. 
So, the first thing you need is to actually read from the file. Since we know that entries are uniform, we can get around without using `getLine();` or anything fancy. There are two ways to do it depending on what you expect to get. 
First way, if you need to read from both files until one of them reaches end:

```
void readLine(string path1, string path2){
    ifstream inOne(path1);
    ifstream inTwo(path2);  

    while( !inOne.eof() & !inTwo.eof() ){
        string strOne, strTwo;

        inOne>>strOne;  
        inTwo>>strTwo;

        cout<<"1 "<<strOne<<endl;
        cout<<"2 "<<strTwo<<endl;
    }
}
```

However, if you need to continue even if one of the files was read, go with something like this:

```
    while( !inOne.eof() | !inTwo.eof() ){
        string strOne, strTwo;

        if(!inOne.eof())
            inOne>>strOne;  
        if(!inTwo.eof())
            inTwo>>strTwo;

        cout<<"1 "<<strOne<<endl;
        cout<<"2 "<<strTwo<<endl;
    }
```

Now, as for the actual formatting you want to perform on each line, you most likely noticed that I did not write anything to handle that. That's because the best way to do that, in my opinion, is to write another function that would do just that. You might call it `formatLine(string line);`. Then using the code I provided, add calls to that function and modify the output accordingly. I cannot tell you what would that look like exactly because, you can define `formatLine();` to return array of elements extracted from the line, or you can return `vector` which is always a good idea, if number of elements might vary. 
Now as for that first line, you might create a function just for reading that one line, since it is very different and might need different formatting anyways.

```
void readFirst(string path){

    ifstream inOne(path, ios::in | ios::binary); //ORed bitfield to get unformatted binary
    char ch=0;

    while(ch != '\n'){
        inOne.get(ch);
        cout<<ch<<endl;

    }

}
```

Then you might want to store each character in a c-string, or append a regular string. Also, don't forget closing each stream after you're finished with it using `inOne.close();`
**UPD.**
You can still use this code for the files you provided as long as there are no white spaces in lines, because extractor `iostream` will treat them as a delimiter and hence as a new line. 
If you however need to make sure that delimiters won't affect orderly extraction, use the last patch of code I included. `ios::binary` will prevent formatting, so you won't lose any of the characters along the way, and you will be able to tell exactly when to move to a new line. It might look something like:

```
void readLine(string path1, string path2){
    ifstream inOne(path1, ios::in | ios::binary);
    ifstream inTwo(path2, ios::in | ios::binary);   

    while( !inOne.eof() | !inTwo.eof() ){
        string strOne, strTwo;

        strOne=readLineBin(inOne);
        strTwo=readLineBin(inTwo);

        cout<<"1 "<<strOne<<endl;
        cout<<"2 "<<strTwo<<endl;
    }
}

string readLineBin(ifstream& in){
    string line="";

    char ch=0;
    while(ch != '\n' & !in.eof()){
        in.get(ch);
        line+=ch;
    }
    return line;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if the lines are different as in the update above.

Comment: @AwaitedOne I added to my original answer

Comment: But it gets each line not the full read( sequence + quality as a whole) together, which is spread on many lines.

Comment: @AwaitedOne You want them to look like this? `@r0/1 TATTCTTCCGCATCCTTCATACTCCTGCCGGTCAGAAA+EDCCCBAAAA@@@@?>===<;;9:99987776554678`

Comment: @AwaitedOne then simply replace `\n` with `@` in `readLinebin()`. This will produce the desired line, however you will lose the `@`, but I don't think it's significant anyways. Note: that since your text file begins with `@`, first line might be an empty string. Also, since new line character is preserved, you'd want to include a code inside to replace it with a space

Comment: No, that is not the way to do. I have many `@@@@@` in quality.

Comment: @AwaitedOne then use the original code. Read one line at the time, and then in the "main" code concatenate them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143178/discussion-between-michael-p-and-awaitedone).